# How to position nandi statue in Hanuman temple?

Tags: temple, hanuman, agamas, vastu-shastra, nandi

In a Hanuman temple near our house there is a nandi statue. Temple is very old . Nandi statue is now coming near the road. I want that it should be placed some where away from road. Hanuman temple is east facing and Nandi statue is north facing. Please advice me how the statue should be placed. Your valuable suggestions will change many things

Comment: You should ask such question to Pundits or Agama Acharyas.

Comment: Yes, like @TheDestroyer said you should be asking this question to a temple priest..or atleast ur family priest..